# Передача DWORD в CreateThread

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Есть следующий код

```
DWORD WINAPI messageDispatcher(LPVOID thread)
{
    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, messageHandler, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(thread));
 
    // Бла бла
}

DWORD thread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, nullptr);
CreateThread(nullptr, 0, messageDispatcher, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(thread), 0, nullptr);
```

При компиляции Visual Studio выдает предупреждения

- warning C4311: reinterpret_cast: усечение указателя из "LPVOID" в "DWORD"
- warning C4302: reinterpret_cast: усечение из "LPVOID" к "DWORD"
- warning C4312: reinterpret_cast: преобразование из "DWORD" в "LPVOID" большего размера

Мне нужно передать идентификатор нужного мне потока в мой поток для того чтобы установить перехват событий мыши. Код должен работать корректно как на x32 системах так и на x64 (при соответствующей компиляции под x32 и x64 естественно) Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передаёте **указатель** на идентификатор нити. *Этот идентификатор должен быть в статической переменной (не в стеке), чтобы поток успел взять его значение.*

```
CreateThread ( nullptr , 0 , messageDispatcher ,
  reinterpret_cast < LPVOID > ( & thread ) , 0 , nullptr ) ;
```

Преобразоваете на правильный указатель и берёте с него значение.

```
DWORD WINAPI messageDispatcher ( LPVOID threadp )
{
  hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx ( WH_MOUSE , messageHandler , 
    GetModuleHandle ( nullptr ) ,
    * reinterpret_cast < DWORD * > ( threadp ) ) ;
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, написать static DWORD thread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, nullptr); ? Это будет работать корректно как и на x32 так и на x64? (при компиляции под x32 и x64 естественно) На одном форуме мне сказали попробовать передавать HANDLE (void*) потока полученного при помощи OpenThread, это лучше чем Ваше предложение? HANDLE так же должен быть объявлен как статическая переменная?

Comment: Передавая аргумент целое число, потом преобразовая в указатель, потом назад это очень некультурно. Передаваемые данные могут быть как аргумент указатель (*некультурно*) , в статической переменной (*глобальной*) если вам это удобно, в динамической памяти (*тогда поток должен удалить память по указателю, когда уже не нужен*).

Comment: Если будете с одним потоком работать, то `static DWORD thread` - сработает. А если с несколькими, то нужен будет массив `DWORD threadid [ N ]`.

Comment: А как тогда сделать культурно? Передать HANDLE потока (OpenThread) ?

Comment: Я всё написал, вы передаёте в поток указатель. Этот указатель указывает на HANDLE потока, который запустил (*родителя*). Тип этого хендла DWORD.

Comment: Спасибо, друг!!

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, тот указатель static DWORD.. нужно ли его удалять или же он сам удалится при DLL_PROCESS_DETACH? (именно выгрузке библиотеки, но не закрытии всего процесса)

Comment: `DWORD thread` это всего-лишь номер процесса. С этим номером ничего делать не надо.